# To be stoked on/about/ to do something

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What's the difference, if any, between these:

```
I'm stoked on going there
I'm stoked about going there
I'm stoked to go there
```

What's the most common?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search of “stoked about” yields about four times more hits than either “stoked on” or “stoked to.”

This matches my expectation, because I don’t recall *ever* hearing someone use “stoked on” or “stoked to.”

Comment: I do remember a native american speaker, who, actually, teachers american slang, saying "I'm stoked on the shoes" in his podcast where he explained the slang-word "stoked".

Comment: @LittleEva, [Webster defines it here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoked) as slang for “being in an enthusiastic or exhilarated state.” Interestingly, in the two examples, one uses “to,” and the other uses “about.” There is even a “stoked that” in the comments.